# Subscribing to a websocket using gorilla/websocket

Tags: go, websocket

I want to use some websocket streams of the [Binance API](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/testnet/en/#websocket-market-streams). I am posting this here because I think **this isn't an issue with the API, but rather my understanding of websockets in general**.

I try to subscribe to a stream as the [official gorilla/websocket example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/echo/client.go) describes:

```golang
conn, res, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial("wss://stream.binance.com/ws/BTCUSD@markPrice", nil)

fmt.Println(conn)
fmt.Println(res)
fmt.Println(err)

for {
    _, message, readErr := conn.ReadMessage()
    if readErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(readErr)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(message)
}
```

The connection is created without errors, but after that, no message gets read.

I think the problem is that the API demands me to subscribe to a stream like so:

```
{
    "method": "SUBSCRIBE",
    "params": [
        "btcusdt@aggTrade",
        "btcusdt@depth"
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

I am aware that a websocket connection starts out with one HTTP request where, as far as I understood, I send this data. But where and when am I supposed to do so? `Dial` doesn't give the option to send anything apart from HTTP headers.

UPDATE:

I managed to send the right request and get the right response as documented [here](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/testnet/en/#subscribe-to-a-stream) by using Conn.WriteJSON:

```golang
type request struct {
    Method string    `json:"method"`
    Params [1]string `json:"params"`
    ID     int       `json:"id"`
}

markPriceReq := request{"SUBSCRIBE", [1]string{"btcusdt@markPrice"}, 1}
conn.WriteJSON(markPriceReq)
```

However, after the initial response no data gets read anymore. Where do I get the actual mark price data from?

Comment: Write the subscription to the connection.  https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.WriteJSON

Comment: @MuffinTop Thanks! I now get the right response { "result": null, "id": 1 }, as described in the API doc. However I still don't know where to read the actual data :/

Comment: Call ReadMessage (as in the question) or ReadJSON (if you want to decode the JSON).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue with your connection url.

All symbols for stream are lowercase and the ws base endpoint in the document link you posted is `wss://stream.binancefuture.com` (**Perpetual/Perpetual Testnet** ws endpoint) but you are using `wss://stream.binance.com` (**Margin/Spot/Savings/Mining** ws endpoint).

Mark price stream is only available for **Perpetual/Perpetual Testnet** ws endpoint. I use *raw stream url*: `wss://stream.binancefuture.com/ws/btcusdt@markPrice` without any issues

This request is for live subscribing/unsubscribing, you only use this when already connected to binance ws and want to subscribe to more streams or unsubscribe to a stream.

```
{
    "method": "SUBSCRIBE",
    "params": [
        "btcusdt@aggTrade",
        "btcusdt@depth"
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

You don't have to use live subscribing/unsubscribing, just use *raw url* like above is fine:

`wss://stream.binancefuture.com/ws/<streamName>` (only one stream) `wss://stream.binancefuture.com/stream?streams=<streamName1>/<streamName2>/<streamName3>` (combined streams)

By using raw url, you are accessed to `<streamName>` (you can also send a request to use live subscribing/unsubscribing after that)